# match string between two commas using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, java, regex

All,
I have the below strings and I want to match string that contains ", Body " followed by any string up to comma as highlighted in bold below

> 30 IN, Ball Valve, Trunnion, Gen manu, CL 900, BW, **Body LTCS**, Metal Seat, Gear Operated, Trim Alloy 825, Full Bore, NACE MR 0175/ISO 15156 -with extended pup-piece as pipe schedule. VBFW 91Z08

> .75 IN, Ball Valve, Gen manu, CL 2500, Flanged, RF, **Body DSS**, PEEK seats, Trim DSS, Reduced Bore -770343.254.1

> 3.75 IN, Ball Valve, Gen manu, CL 2500, Flanged, RF,**Swing Body DSS**, PEEK seats, Trim DSS, Reduced Bore -770343.254.1

> 16 IN, Ball Valve, Trunnion, Gen manu, CL 900, Flanged, RTJ, Split Body, **Body CS + Alloy 625 Cla**d, Soft Seat, Gear Operated, Trim Inconel 625, Full Bore, NACE MR 0175/ISO 15156 -AS PER DATASHEET RE-185942

I am struggling to write a regex as I just started learning it. any help is greatly appreciated.

below is the pattern what I have tried so far

`(?<=,) Body +\w+`

https://regex101.com/r/tMlQby/4

Comment: Chaitanya Vardhan - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want to do with the `Swing Body` line, since that doesn't match your stated pattern of `, Body`, but for the others you can use:

```
(?<=, )Body .+?(?=,)
```

`.` will match any character, including whitespace. `?` means make it a lazy quantifier (stop at the first comma you run into). And `?=` is a positive lookahead.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tMlQby/5)

Comment: This will fail if you do not have any character between `Body` and `,` e.g. for the string `30 IN, Ball Valve, Trunnion, Gen manu, CL 900, BW, Body, Metal Seat, Gear Operated` or for the string `30 IN, Ball Valve, Trunnion, Gen manu, CL 900, BW, Body , Metal Seat, Gear Operated`. It is because you have assumed that there will always be a space followed by some characters after `Body`

Comment: OP asked for a match where `Body` is always followed by a space and another string. If you don't want that, you can use `Body.*?` instead of `Body .+?`.

Comment: Exactly, that's the point. That `another string` can be space or an empty string. However, even after this change, your regex will fail if there is no space before `Body` because you have assumed that there will always be a space between `,` and `Body`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex, `(?<=,)[\s\w]*Body .*?(?=,)`

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/bdy4KX/5) for a demo.

**Explanation:**

1. `(?<=,)` is looking behind positively for a comma
2. `[\s\w]*` matches any number of whitespace character or a word character
3. `Body`  matches `Body` followed by a space character
4. `.*?` matches any character lazily
5. `(?=,)` is looking ahead positively for a comma

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=,)[^,]*Body[^,]+(?=,)
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ExFaRw/2/)

1. `(?<=,)` - Positive lookbehind assertion that the string must be preceded by a ','.
2. `[^,]*` - Matches 0 or more non-comma characters.
3. `Body` - Matches 'Body'.
4. `[^,]+` - Matches 1 or more non-comma characters.
5. `(?=,)` - Positive lookahead assertion that the string must be followed by a ','.

If you assume that there is always a space following the initial comma and you do *not* want to match that, then use:

```
(?<=, )[^,]*Body[^,]+(?=,)
```

If you assume that there *must* be a space following the initial comma and you *do* want to match that, then use:

```
(?<=,) [^,]*Body[^,]+(?=,)
```